# Cannot port-forward SSH service port to FreeNAS internal IP (local network IP)

Tags: port-forwarding, freenas

I'm trying to port forward the SSH service port (22) to my FreeNAS local IP which is 192.168.0.225

I do believe that it is a static IP.

---

*My goal is to be able to access my FreeNAS server remotely.* I can already access the FreeNAS server from within in the local network.

---

I am using an online open port checker to see if port 22 is open, which it isn't.

I don't think it's an issue with my modem, since I am able to port forward port 3389 for windows remote desktop. (port 3389 shows as open when I use a open port checker)

My question is: How do I open port forward the SSH service port (22)? I think I may have missed something when doing the configuration for the FreeNAS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to configure your (unidentified) border device to accept connections on port 22 and forward them to port 22 on 192.168.0.225.

You should also confirm that there are no firewall devices in the path that need to have port 22 opened too. For example can you connect to port 22 on 192.168.0.225 from another device on the 'inside'. If you can then you should check that external connections to port 22 are arriving at your border device.

Take action as appropriate.